# How to store state in Puppet?

Tags: puppet

I have started using Puppet recently and one of the areas that I am struggling with is saving the "state". Maybe the following example tasks will help :

1. Use Puppet to install some software (Apache httpd or database)
2. Use Puppet to create some services (lets say database or httpd instance)
3. Use Puppet to startup services (lets say startup database instance)
4. Use Puppet to request SSL certs and import them once ready (Apache)
5. Copy information about server details into some database
6. And many more...

In all of this, I would like to save the state. Say once the SSL task is complete, save the state, this way when Puppet runs the next time, it knows that SSL is generated and skips this task all together. I am currently doing this the "cheesey" way, ie I am creating "files" to indicate that the task is completed and in the next run I check for the presence of the file to allow me to make that decision.
 Is there a more elegant way of achieving this ? Maybe a custom fact ? I am really curious to know how others are using Puppet to store and retrieve state of their tasks.

**EDIT** : Adding more details for Alex
One of the tasks is to update an internal company database with details such as the server name, name of the db instance created and such. This task needs to be completed only once and not every 30 minutes (30 minutes is how often the Puppet agent runs).

Comment: People use portable instances that come from (for example) Vagrant boxes or Docker images for this. Provisioning those with Puppet will do what you want automatically.

Comment: @user, if you provide the actual code you are using, I can give my thoughts on a cleaner implementation. At the moment, I am not completely sure what the problem is that you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood question correctly, I think that all "states" that you want to check from the list above can be easily be checked with either [onlyif](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/types/exec.html#exec-attribute-onlyif) or [unless](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/types/exec.html#exec-attribute-unless)

Example: from aboves list nr1. You have installed apache and you want to check next time whether its installed or not.

```
exec { 'install_apache':
command     => '/usr/bin/apt-get install apache2 apache2-doc apache2-utils',
refreshonly => true,
path        => ['/usr/bin', '/bin', '/sbin'],
unless   => 'apt-cache search apache2', }
```

so in this case you will check with `unless` whether apache is already installed, that is if exit status of command apt-cache returns 0 (true), command will not be executed.

This can be used to check whether SSL is created and even database queries.